# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: con.mysql.jdbc.Driver 1

Tags: java, mysql, classnotfoundexception

I have written down the code in Eclipse .. I even put connector jar file in project and set classpath too but it still throws `RuntimeException`.

```
package len;
import java.sql.*;

public class dbcon {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{Class.forName("con.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost//sample","root","");
    Statement s= con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("select * from user1 ");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    }
    con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Should be `"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`

Comment: yes, it is just a typo **con** -> **com**

Answer (score 3):

Use "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```